# Как правильно читать макет для верстки?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как научиться правильно читать макет сайта для верстки?
То есть, как должен вести себя элемент при клике на него или при наведении курсором мыши? Как должен переключаться слайдер-карусель - только мышкой или нужно автоматическое переключение? Что должно происходить с элементами при прокрутке страницы - фиксировать их или не фиксировать, плавная прокрутка или резко? Ну и все в таком роде.

Answer (score 3):

Всё перечисленное нужно спрашивать у заказчика, менеджера, или у дизайнера в переписке. Или просить техзадание. Или бывает в слоях и комментариях фотошопа написано. Потом с опытом и скоростью программирования вы можете многие из таких вещей писать не спрашивая, самостоятельно выбирая наиболее вероятный и лучший вариант, и потом быстро переделывать, когда укажут, что предполагалось не так. Переделать бывает быстрее, чем ждать ответа от занятого заказчика или сотрудника. Таким образом опытный верстальщик может задавать мало вопросов, потому что берёт на себя многие решения. Но только из опыта, а не боится спросить. Если опыта нет и не спрашивать, то будет беда.

Comment: Спасибо, понятно. Я только начинаю работать с заказчиками, поэтому было не совсем все ясно.